# STALE is to STEAL as 89475 is to

Tags: meaning

What means these question on "[okcupid.com](http://okcupid.com)"? this is a profile question.

Comment: I would guess 89547

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a personality/IQ test and not about the English language.

Comment: @Mari-Lou, I think it is on-topic. He is asking about the meaning of a particular structure in English: A is to B as C is to D.

Comment: @dangph your comment and answer posted below explains the meaning of this structure. If the OP wanted to know, he has his answer, and he should upvote your contribution. As the question is currently formulated, it is either off-topic or just general reference. There isn't much more a user could say, unless you went into the grammar, syntax, and history of online quizzes. :)

Comment: Hi, Mohammed. Welcome to EL&U. Please have a look at the quick tour of [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what questions are off topic here. Also, um, you realize that you're asking for help on your, umm... profile, right? It won't reflect *you* ! But good luck!

Comment: It's just a cipher in the context of a dating site in order to help you see a match level in the wide fields of numbers, intelligence and logical reasoning. You convert the alphabetical values to numerical values on the provided sample to function as the encryption key and apply it to the unsolved sample to find your answer. Just answer this question honestly, don't let others find the answer for you to answer this question, that would defeat the purpose of the dating site, unless of course you want to date someone else that is deceitful and pretentious, then, by all means do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a question to test your ability to reason analogically. Some examples of such questions:

- Hat is to head as socks are to ...? (Feet.)
- Fish is to water as bird is to ...? (Air.)

You find these sorts of questions a lot on IQ tests.

Comment: I would like to add this comment to explain that the purpose of this question is purely to measure how one deals with this question to be able to see if that matches other peoples wavelength and interests. OkCupid is, after all, a dating site, and the questions there are to tools to help you find people that match your wants and needs, so your answer is accurate and describes the core of the question, but I hope this addition will show the intent of the question in the context as well, which is, in my opinion, a valid addition.